# detecting 2 finger press at the same time windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, multi-touch

I am planning to make a simple multi player game that Contains 2 buttons and the players must press the two buttons at the same time and and the game must show a popup if one player release the button.
**My problem is that i don't know how to make the app UI detect the two finger press**

Comment: If you want to make a game with multiple touch inputs, why not use the XNA studio? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx

Comment: xna studio does not support wp8.1

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't provide a total count of presses, but each PointerPressed and PointerReleased event includes the ID of the pointer being pressed or released. The app can keep use this to keep track of the state of each ID and to tell how many IDs are currently pressed.

Here's an example using Xaml pointer events. CoreWindow pointer events will work the same but the exact classes and properties will be slightly different.

```
List<uint> pointerIDs = new List<uint>(10);
private void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pointerIDs.Add(e.Pointer.PointerId);
    Debug.WriteLine("Pointer {0} pressed. {1} total pressed", e.Pointer.PointerId, NumDown);
}

private void OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pointerIDs.Remove(e.Pointer.PointerId);
    Debug.WriteLine("Pointer {0} released. {1} total pressed", e.Pointer.PointerId, NumDown);
}

int NumDown
{
    get
    {
        return pointerIDs.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think that you understand my problem take a look at the pic
http://imageshack.com/a/img538/2206/ucaFGJ.png
i want to press button 1 and button 2 at the same time

Comment: Only one button can be pushed at a time. You can implement your own hotspots and detect multiple PointerPressed and PointerReleased events in them.